# Svelte Native with SQLite

Tags: sqlite, nativescript, svelte, svelte-native

I have been trying to incorporate sqlite to my svelte native app; I want to store information from a data collection form(data input into textfields) and store them and i have looked around and so far still to no avail. any kind of help for this svelte native challenge would be highly appreciated.

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.